# Retrieving .NET generic host reference globally

Tags: c#, .net-6.0

Let's consider this Generic Host based .NET 6 simple application (no ASP.NET)

```
internal sealed class Program
{
    private static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        await Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
            {
                services.AddHostedService<MyService>();
            })
            .RunConsoleAsync();
    }
}
```

Is there a way to retrieve the IHost instance reference globally (I mean, without the DI mechanisms)?

I am looking for something like:

```
IHost host = Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Context.CurrentHost
```

**EDIT**

Of course, inside Main I can get the host, but I want to access it elsewhere, from any point in the code (globally as per the title, without creating an app global variable).
As a similar example, in .net we can access the current application domain as AppDomain.CurrentDomain.

Comment: There is no innate reason to only have one host at a time. The context of your code might be so specific that you know which one is meant or that there is actually one currently. But i don't see how the system can help here without reducing the frameworks usability. You need to store and use the created host or hosts by yourself and then select them via a proper created facility you have created. Besides that if there was something like what you where hoping for it sounds like the way to create hard to test code (you can't get rid of that dependency if you explicitly want a non di feature).

Comment: @Ralf Makes sense. If you want to put your comment as answer, I would choose it as the correct one.

Comment: I only give context on why that type of solution you want to have sound like a bad or at least incomplete idea. @Guru Stron 's answer is actually on the right track on giving you the host instance. The "how i get it to the place i want to use it" is missing but that needs more context about what you have and might only be solvable by you especially regarding the "without di" part. Or that might be something for an additional question with more info on what you have and why you want it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct answer to the question is that The IHost object is not like an application domain. While there is a concept of global current application domain for a running application, there is not such concept of a global current IHost instance. There can be multiple IHost instances in an application, so it makes sense that the application code takes responsibility to track them.
Hence, the correct solution is to store the IHost reference and provide the mechanism to access it globally in the application code.

Answer (score 4):

You can build and run host in separate steps:

```cs
// host can be assigned to some static field/property
// Or passed somehow else to the place where you want to use it.
var host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
    {
       // ...
    })
    .UseConsoleLifetime()
    .Build();
await host.RunAsync();
```